# Postgres TIMESTAMP index and query performance

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timestamp

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CHANGE_REQUESTS (
    ID             UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    FIELD_ID             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    LAST_CHANGE_DATE    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

And I'm always going to be running the exact same query on it:

```
select * from change_requests where last_change_date > now() - INTERVAL '10 min';
```

The size of the table is going to be anywhere from 750k to 1million rows on average.

My question is how can I make sure the query is always very fast? I'm thinking of adding an index on `last_change_date`, but I'm not sure if that will do anything. I tried it (with only 1 row in the table right now) and got this explain:

```
create index change_requests__dt_index
    on change_requests (last_change_date);
```

```
Seq Scan on change_requests  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=1 width=28)
  Filter: (last_change_date > (now() - '00:10:00'::interval))
```

So it doesn't appear to use the index at all.

Will this index actually help? If not, what else could I do? Thanks!

Comment: Just one row isn't much, try again with (a lot) more rows. In general your index is good would support the query. You could try and see if you can even improve it by putting an index on (last_change_date, id, field_id)`. Then the whole query could be answered by the index alone.

Comment: Yeah I figured 1 row wouldn't show me how fast it would actually be, but wouldn't it at least mention that it's using the index? As for putting the index on (last_change_date, id, field_id), could you explain what that would do? I'm never actually searching on any column besides last_change_date, so what would adding those other fields to the index do?

Comment: If it doesn't decide to use the index, because it's pointless for just one row, no, it won't say it uses the index. And you want the other columns in the output. That's why an index including them could be beneficial. It can directly be used to get these columns without the need to read them from the table first.

Comment: Interesting, ok. I didn't know that it takes the number of rows into account when deciding to use the index or not, thanks for the info. I actually just generated 1 million rows in chunks of 250k at a time, and finally when I hit 1 million rows in the table it changed the explain to start using the index. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Sometimes you can use ```SET enable_seqscan = OFF;```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your index is perfect for the task. You see the sequential scan in the execution plan because you don't have a realistic amount of test data in the table, and for very small tables the overhead of using the index is not worth the effort (you'd have to process more 8kB database blocks).

Always test with realistic amounts of data. That will safe you some pain later on.